# Which Cloud Technology/Service?

Tags: cloud

I am a long time desktop developer who is struggling a little to choose a cloud technology.
What I need to do: Periodically spin up a number of machines to run a task that runs until completion. The number of machines and length of task both vary, but 20-100 machines and a run time of 2-30 minutes are good estimates. So I might need a 5 minute task on 60 machines and then 10 minutes later I'll need a 15 minute task on 40 machines, for example.

I've tried researching this but I don't have the background to understand a lot of the websites I've been reading.

It seems like AWS could do this but when I start reading there's "containers" and "event driven compute" and "auto scaling" and "elastic beanstalk" and "lambda". Lambda actually sounds like what I want, but after about two hours of reading it turns out lambda is limited to 60 seconds of run time.

Can someone get me started by pointing me at a cloud technology that would be appropriate for my service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the cloud providers will have a solution that can do this.

In theory the most open approach is to use OpenStack which should allow you change cloud providers: https://www.openstack.org/software/

In practice, at this time you will probably find AWS has the most discussion/blogs/examples on the web to help you started - take a look at AWS Cloudformation and then maybe search for some examples: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/

Answer (score 0):

You can define different types of jobs: OS Command Job, SQL Script Job, Multi-task Job etc. using oracle cloud Control, but I can't point you to a specific service because I don't know the exact nature of the jobs that you want to run.

I encourage you to take a look at what [Oracle Cloud](http://bit.ly/1z43pwJ) has to offer. You can try each of the services for free.

Meanwhile, take a look at this [document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/doc.1111/e24473/jobs.htm) that explains how automatic jobs can be created and what options you have to define jobs on different targets.
Maybe if you give me more details regarding the jobs you need to run I will be able to point you to a specific service.